# Excel Pivot table range reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Hi I’m trying to make some calculation starting from data stored in an excel pivot table.

I know there is a `GetPivotData` function, which is very useful, but it only allows retrieving single values. I’d like to use worksheets function to “query” my data (for example, sum some values in a column, without filtering the pivot table), but I can’t find a way to easily reference the range of the pivot table.
The “structure” of the table may be assumed to be fixed, but not the data in it: the best solution I found is to write a `UDF` function to get the reference to the range of the table:

```
 Function getPvRange(firstcell As Range) As Range
    Set getPvRange = firstcell.PivotTable.TableRange1
 End Function
```

I can use this function in my formulas. I was wondering if there is a simple (I mean without defining dynamic range names) direct way (I mean, not using VBA), to reference the Pivot Table range?

Answer (score 1):

If your sheet is simple, using excel Offset function is a way to get Pivot Table Range as the function you provided. for example, created a named range and assign range as

```
=offset($A$1,,,counta($a:$a),15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refer to cells within a pivot table as normal cells, you can disable the automatically generated `GetPivotData` functions. Bring up the pivot table toolbar, click add buttons, and select `'Generate GetPivotData'`. You can then use the new button to toggle the automated formulas.

Or are you trying to do something a bit more complicated? If so, please could you post an example?

Comment: I have some data in a table which are summarized in a pivot table. I'd like to make further calculation on the summarized data: I was wondering what is the best way to refer to a range in the pivot table (which can growth whenever I add data in the original table)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please could you post an example of how the table might look before and after the relevant range expands? I suspect you're going to have to delve into VBA or define dynamic ranges, I'm afraid.