# Can I reference a pivot table name instead of a R1C1 style reference

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 4 pivot tables that i want to aggregate in a regular table.
The table structure is as follows...
[image]

Columns B through E get the Grand Total from the Pivot tables referenced in Column A.  So, the question is: can I replace the pivot table location in `=GETPIVOTDATA("SP",$BE$2)` with something like `INDEX([pivotTableName])`?
The resulting formula would then be: `=GETPIVOTDATA("SP",INDEX([pivotTableName]))`

The INDEX command returns #REF and I checked ([Reference pivot table by name Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811493/reference-pivot-table-by-name-excel-2010)) and ([Excel Pivot table range reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135298/excel-pivot-table-range-reference)) but those solutions use VB.

Comment: Index takes arguments as well. What is the problem with the correct syntax above of a single cell reference in the GetPivotData function ? And BE2 is not R1C1. I am struggling to make sense of your question. You have the simplest of the GETPIVOTDATA argument structures. Any attempt with Index etc would add more complexity.

Comment: I have a similar need. For some reason, Excel doesn't list the Pivot Table by name when using formulas that refer to tables. So, to use the GETPIVOTDATA function, you need to refer to the pivot table by its R1C1 address instead of its name (like you can do with tables).

Answer (score 1):

### Turning off the `GETPIVOTDATA` function

1. Go to Options, by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hitting <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Click the **Formulas** tab.
3. Uncheck **`Use GetPivotData functions for PivotTable references`**.

[image: Turning off GETPIVOTDATA3]

---

Now you can refer to the pivot table with regular cell references:

[image: Turning off GETPIVOTDATA4]

Comment: thanks for the idea, but what I want, based on your table would be to have a table with a column that contains the names of the pivot tables and the formula would then reference the pivot table name instead of the cell reference.  I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Agreed. Also, why is it then names can be defined for Pivot tables when they cannot be referenced: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-f8b73921-3494-48e2-a271-ce6c5d371cf4